# Button won't stay OFF

Tags: javascript, html

I have this set up so when the hint button is “ON “the target are will highlight when you start to drag the item. This works fine. But when I switch the button to “OFF” as soon as I start to drag an item the button returns to the “ON” position and highlights the target area. How can the button stay “OFF” so no highlighting occurs?
Here's the button code (full code in fiddle)

```
function onoff() {
currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
if (currentvalue == "Off") {
  document.getElementById("onoff").value = "On";
} else {
  document.getElementById("onoff").value = "Off";
}
}
```

Here's jsfiddle [Button won't stay OFF](https://jsfiddle.net/aceuk007/8mw1s2zj/)

Comment: `if((document.getElementById("onoff").value="On")` You're assigning a value here instead of comparing.  Use `==` (or `===`) instead of `=`.

Comment: its working man in fiddle

Comment: FYI never use more than one `<h1>` tag, that's not proper HTML design, a better implementation is to use the container you currently have for your `<h1>` and assign a class to it, then apply CSS styling to get the look you want

Comment: How is `onoff` called?

Comment: Yep, I agree with @James Thrope. Look at line 96 as an example in your fiddle. So every time you think you are checking if it is on, you are actually reassigning the value to on.

Comment: @AGE html5 allows and encourages the use of multiple h1 tags on a page

Comment: @Pete I didn't notice the OP was using HTML5 (thanks JSFiddle), good call.

Comment: @James Thrope Thanks works perfectly. Do you know if there is a shortcut way of writing (data === "item1" || data === "item2" || data === "item3" || data === "item4") like (data === "item1" to data === "item4") as my list will be over 100 items.Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to the point, in your Fiddle, the function `ondragstart` has a bunch of conditionals doing assignments, for example: `document.getElementById("onoff").value="On"`, for comparing the value, you should use `==`, and for camparing the value and the type, you should use `===`.

Heres how it should be in your `ondragstart` function:

```
if((document.getElementById("onoff").value === "On") && (data === "item1" || data === "item2" || data === "item3" || data === "item4")){
  (document.getElementById("fruit").style.color = "red") && (document.getElementById("veg").style.color = "black") && (document.getElementById("games").style.color = "black");
}
else if((document.getElementById("onoff").value === "On") && (data === "item5" || data === "item6" || data === "item7" || data === "item8")){
  (document.getElementById("veg").style.color = "red") && (document.getElementById("fruit").style.color = "black") && (document.getElementById("games").style.color = "black");
}
else if((document.getElementById("onoff").value === "On") && (data === "item9" || data === "item10" || data === "item11" || data === "item12")){
  (document.getElementById("games").style.color = "red") && (document.getElementById("fruit").style.color = "black") && (document.getElementById("veg").style.color = "black");
}
else if((document.getElementById("onoff").value === "Off") &&  (data === "item1" || data === "item2" || data === "item3" || data === "item4" || data === "item5" || data === "item6" || data === "item7" || data === "item8" || data === "item9" || data === "item10" || data === "item11" || data === "item12")){
  (document.getElementById("fruit").style.color = "black") && (document.getElementById("veg").style.color = "black") && (document.getElementById("games").style.color = "black");
}
```